# C# Count even numbers from console imputed string

Tags: c#, string, count

I have this problem to solve in C#: the user enters integers from console (not a fixed number of int, but unlimited numbers of int, as much as he wants) one by one and when the user enters the value "x" the program should stop and should count and print how many even numbers the string contains.

Example

The user enters these integers from console:

```
2
5
8
4
1
6
9
2
5
x
```

and the result should be:

```
5
```

This is my code so far:

```cs
using System;

public class TestNumericDataTypesOperations
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        string[] a = new string[100];

        int b=0;
        int total = 0;


        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            a[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            int b = int.Parse(a);
            if (b % 2 == 0)

                total++;


            if (a[i] == "x")
            {
                break;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(total);
        }

    }
}
```

I get error CS1503 and CS0136 on line 17 (`int b = int.Parse(a);`) and warning CS0219 on line 10 (`int b=0;`) and warning CS8601 on line 16 (`a[i] = Console.ReadLine();`).

Thank you!

Comment: Hints: 1) for `int.Parse(a)`, what's the type of `a`, and how do you expect that to be parsed as a single integer? 2) You appear to be declaring `b` twice. Did you intend to do that? I'd probably encourage you to disable nullable reference types until you're more comfortable with the basics of C#.

Comment: the input is in a single line?

Comment: Typo?  Did you mean to parse `a[i]` instead of `a`?  Did you forget to remove the `b` outside the loop that you don't use?  You appear to only be looking at the error *codes*, but are you reading the error *messages*?  What are those messages telling you, and what are you asking about them?

Comment: All of what you said above is true and they generate errors, but I don't know how to fix them in order to obtain the desired result.

Comment: @User_PI612: Now is a good time to clarify and specify what you're asking.  If the underlying question is "How do I do my assignment?" then that's too broad, your assignment is part of your work and ultimately your responsibility.  We can help with specific issues you encounter along the way.  (There are multiple problems in the code shown.)  If the underlying question is about a specific error on a specific line of code, please indicate which error and what the error message is telling you and what you're asking about that error (e.g. why you don't think it should be failing).

Comment: I am trying to fix this two errors [CS1503 and CS0136 on line 17 ('''int b = int.Parse(a);''')] so that I could count the even numbers from a console imputed string.

Comment: @User_PI612: And what are those error messages telling you?  Have you used your favorite search engine to look up the documentation for those error codes?  Have you used your favorite search engine to find other examples of those errors and how they were resolved?  Can you indicate why you expect that line of code to *not* produce an error?  It honestly sounds like you're not even *reading the error message* and are just immediately giving up and asking us to do your homework for you.

Comment: Yes, it was my mistake, there are 5 indeed.

Comment: @David: Of course that I have searched but since I haven't found anything similar until now, I will continue to search, and by not giving up I will solve this problem, eventually. Thank you!

Comment: We don't know these CS numbers by heart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue:

```
int.Parse(a);
```

`a` here is an **array**, not a string. You need to use the specific entry in `a` instead.

But there's a worse issue the compiler missed: you're doing this *before* checking whether the input is `x`, meaning you're expecting to see non-integer values here at least once. That will cause an exception the compiler can't anticipate, when the program is running. You should look at `int.TryParse()` instead, and move this part to *after* checking if the user wants to quit.

Then we have the warning for this line:

```
int b = 0;
```

The problem here is this variable is never used. Rather, inside the loop the variable is *re-declared*: `int b = int.Parse(a);`. Either remove the `int` from the later line, or (for preference) remove the first line entirely.

Finally we have the warning for this line:

```
a[i] = Console.ReadLine();
```

This relates to a new-ish C# feature for nullable reference checks. The `Console.Readline()` method is much older than these checks, and for historical reasons doesn't mark its result as not null. You can either [turn off these checks completely](https://csharpplayersguide.com/articles/disable-null-checking.html#:%7E:text=Under%20Build%20%3E%20General%2C%20scroll%20down,a%20pre%2DC%23%209%20state.) (not recommended) or add a special [null-forgiveness operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving):
`a[i] = Console.ReadLine()!;`

There is one final issue, on this line:

```
Console.WriteLine(total);
```

This line is still inside the loop, which means it will re-write the total on every entry. You probably want to do this only once, *after* the loop.

But for fun, since we don't ever use the original inputs again, I'd write it like this (no need for an array):

```
public static void Main()
{
    int total = 0;
    string input;
    while(  (input = Console.ReadLine()) != "x")
    {
        if (int.TryParse(input, out int b) && b % 2 == 0)
            total++;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(total);
}
```

And this is useful to demonstrate how to call `int.TryParse()`

For more fun, and to give you exposure to some advanced language features, we could add this method (needs a `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top):

```cs
public static IEnumerable<int> ReadData()
{
    string input;
    while ( (input = Console.ReadLine()) != "x")
    {
        if (int.TryParse(input, out int i))
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

And then the actual program method is a one-liner (needs `using System.Linq;`):

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(ReadData().Count(i => i%2 == 0));
}
```

Comment: Side note: you can get rid of `Where` and move condition into `Count`: `ReadData().Count(item => item % 2 == 0)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Ooh, of course. I always forget `Count()` has an overload with a predicate.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Let's extract a method to read integer numbers:

```
// true, if we read an integer value (result)
// false, if user wants to stop adding items
private static bool TryReadInt(out int result) {
  result = 0;

  // We keep asking user until
  while (true) {
    string input = Console.ReadLine(); 

    // user writes "x" 
    if (input.Trim() == "x") {
      result = 0;

      return false;
    }

    // Or provide a valid integer value
    if (int.TryParse(input, out result))
      return true;
 
    Console.WriteLine("Not a valid integer, please, try again");
  }
}
```

Then we can implement the `Main` routine like this (note, that we don't want any collection since all we have to do is to count, not provide all even number):

```
public static void Main() {
  int total = 0;

  while (TryReadInt(out var item)) {
    if (item % 2 == 0)
      total += 1;
  }

  Console.WriteLine(total);
}
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6GOj9g)

Comment: Couldn't we move the TryReadInt call into the while loop's condition instead of `true` ? I always feel a little dirty, when I do `while(true) { if(!condition) break; }` :D => https://dotnetfiddle.net/XP5Ila

Comment: @Fildor: Thank you! `while(true) { if () break; }` was really ugly.

Comment: If I were to extract the read, I'd move all of the reads there have it return an array or enumerable, rather than needing to use an `out`. Hmm... maybe I'll write that for the end of my own answer.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn: You are quite right, and then you can query this `IEnumerable<int>` with a help of Linq... But this solution being compact and easy to read can appear too complex for the OP.